# Correct syntax for a

Tags: java, arrays, string, object

I can't get the correct syntax for constructor of the public code. So this is the main:

```
public class Main_code {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Code C = new Code;
        C.code();
        C.make();
    }
}
```

And this is the public code:

```
public class code {

    int x;
    int numbers;
    int [] result;
```

This is the constructor:

```
public code (){

    this.x=0;
    this.numbers [] = {6, 3, 8, 9, 1, 4, 7};
    this.result= new int[x];
}
```

and finally, this is the void:

```
public void make (){

        for (int i=0; i<numbers.lenght){
            if(this.numbers[i]<5){
                this.result [x] = this.numbers[i]
            }
        }
        for (int e=0; e<this.result.length;e++){
            System.out.println (this.result[e]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show us the error messages you're getting. Tell us what you think they mean.

Comment: Is `Code` with a capital C supposed to be `code` in lower case? because they're different identifiers

Answer (score 1):

```
this.numbers [] = {6, 3, 8, 9, 1, 4, 7};
```

is invalid, `numbers` is of type `int`, not an array

even if it was an array you just do it

```
this.numbers = new int[] {6, 3, 8, 9, 1, 4, 7};
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the brackets when creating a new instance. Instead of `Code c = new Code;` write `Code c = new Code(); //<-added brackets`. Also, Java is case sensitive, so you must change the name of the class and the Constructor to `Code` or java won't recognize the construtor in the `Main_code` class. And you should read throug the [java namig conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html), just for a cleaner code.